# Remove trailing slashes at the end of url

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I know there's a bajillian number of questions with this title and I've tried them all. What I'm trying to do is redirect

```
localhost/site/tours/picnics/
```

to

```
localhost/site/tours/picnics
```

but every code I've tried, (this one for instance)

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s(.+?)/+[?\s]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

redirects me to `localhost/picnics` for some reason. I don't understand why it's  happening. I've even tried `RewriteBase /site/` but it didn't make any difference. Can someone point out the problem in this code?

**Edit:** Here's my complete htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteBase /site/
RewriteRule ^destinations/(.*)$ destinations.php?destId=$1 [NC,L]
#RewriteRule ^tours/? tour-listing.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s(.+?)/+[?\s]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^tours/?(.*)$ tour-listing.php?cat=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^tour/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$ tour.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^hotel/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$ hotel-details.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: In localhost/site/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your rule to this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)/+[?\s]
RewriteRule /$ /%1 [R=301,L,NE]
```

`$1` captures value relative to your current directory only but `%1` is being captured from `%{THE_REQUEST}` that has original and full REQUEST URL.

Comment: Make sure to keep this rule just below `RewriteBase` line

Comment: It works but it keeps adding a / after `localhost`, i.e. everytime I go to the link `localhost/site/tours/picnic/` it becomes `localhost//site/tours/picnic`, going again `localhost///site/tours/picnic/` and again `localhost////site/tours/picnic/`